# Excel fails to open Python-generated CSV files

Tags: microsoft-excel, python, csv, osx-mavericks

I have many Python scripts that output CSV files. It is occasionally convenient to open these files in Excel. After installing OS X Mavericks, Excel no longer opens these files properly: Excel doesn't parse the files and it duplicates the rows of the file until it runs out of memory. Specifically, when Excel attempts to open the file, a prompt appears that reads: "File not loaded completely."

Example of code I'm using to generate the CSV files:

```
import csv
with open('csv_test.csv', 'wb') as f:
writer = csv.writer(f)
writer.writerow([1,2,3])
writer.writerow([4,5,6])
```

Even the simple file generated by the above code fails to load properly in Excel. However, if I open the CSV file in a text editor and copy/paste the text into Excel, parse it with text to columns, and then save as CSV from Excel, then I can reopen the CSV file in Excel without issue. Do I need to pass an additional parameter in my scripts to make Excel parse the CSV files the same way it used to? Or is there some setting I can change in OS X Mavericks or Excel? Thanks.

Comment: Excel tends to be specific about what kind of format it expects in regards to CSV. Maybe some character (like a BOM for Unicode) is mixing up Excel. Have you tried to import it as a text file to see if the problem isn't just about CSV recog?

Answer (score 1):

Compare two identical csv files, one made by python as shown above, and a supposedly identical one made by excel.

Use the `diff` utility from a terminal window;

```
diff -u python.csv excel.csv
```

That should show you the difference between the files.